# Redirect user after login with react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-router

I'm using react redux with Next.js and I want to redirect the user to a certain page if he matches the requirement. I added it in my `useEffect` and it works, but every time when I go back to the home page it redirects again to the same page. It works fine If I refresh the page which is going to clear the redux state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const validateUser = (services: ServiceType[]) => {
      if (services.length === 0) {
        router.push('/dashboard/expert/onboard');
      } else {
        router.push(
          '/dashboard/expert/[expertname]?view=overview',
          `/dashboard/expert/${userProfile.expertProfile.name}?view=overview`
        );
      }
    };
    if (userProfile) {
      if (userProfile.isVerified) {
        if (nextPath && nextPath.as) {
          router.push(nextPath.href, nextPath.as);
        } else if (userProfile.isExpert) {
          setModalVisible(false);
          if (services) {
            validateUser(services);
          }
          // setAlreadySignedUpModalVisible(true);
        } else if (loginResponse && loginResponse.expertApplications.rejected > 0) {
          setModalVisible(false);
          setApplicationRejectedModalVisible(true);
        } else if (loginResponse && loginResponse.expertApplications.pending > 0) {
          setModalVisible(false);
          setApplicationReceivedModalVisible(true);
          setIsPendingExpert(true);
        } else {
          if (nextPath) {
            router.push(nextPath.href);
          }
          setModalVisible(false);
        }
      } else {
        setModalVisible(false);
        setEmailVerifyModalVisible(true);
      }
    }
  }, [
    loginResponse,
    setAlreadySignedUpModalVisible,
    setApplicationReceivedModalVisible,
    setApplicationRejectedModalVisible,
    setEmailVerifyModalVisible,
    setModalVisible,
    userProfile,
    nextPath,
    setIsPendingExpert,
    services,
  ]);
```

Comment: setting the variable used to navigate to its default state after calling `router.push` could be a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to redirect *at the moment* when the user logged in and is validated.

That is reacting to some specific event, so you need some kind of "**event handler**".

`useEffect` is **not an event handler**, `useEffect` is for "keeping state synchronized".

So `useEffect` in your case wants to redirect whenever the app has a specific state, which is given no matter if the user has just logged in or already was logged in earlier.
(e.g. note that `useEffect` always gets called at least once when the component is loaded the first time, so that the state is initially synchronized.)

### solution 1

It is possible to kind of "map" and event to the state by including the *moment-it-happended* into the state. This is not always trivial, because *"it just happended"* means *"nothing contradictive happened since then"*, and you might not be able to monitor (or even know about) all conflicting events.

So, your event-state is not only *"logged in and is validated"*. I think you could describe the needed state like:
"*login state has changed since user is on page AND is logged in AND is valid*"

E.g.

```
const [ hasLoggedInSinceOnPage, setHasLoggedInSinceOnPage ] = useState(false);
...
loginRequest.then( (xyz)=>{
    yourLoginCode(xyz);
    setHasLoggedInSinceOnPage(true);
});
...
useEffect(()=>{
    setHasLoggedInSinceOnPage(false);
}, [ currentPage ]);
```

Another idea would be a state like `wasRedirectedAlready`.

### solution 2

I would try, if possible, to call the `router.push` directly as a consequence of the login event (i.e. not using useEffect). That probably requires some redesign of the code. It also might sometimes be not possible in a clean way (I'm not absolutely sure about that).

E.g.:

```
loginRequest.then( (xyz)=>{
    validate(xyz).then( (isValid)=>{
        router.push('...');
    });
});
```